# Ajax Validation Engine: Pass extra parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using the ajax `ajaxNameCall` function to check if a username exists in the database then alert the user if that username is taken or not. I have it working however I need an extra check due to updates. If admin wants to update a users record the check runs against the username sees that user already exists and produces the message. I want to pass an extra parameter of the userID so that I can avoid this situation. Is there any way to use the `extraData` field in ajax validator to give it the userID?

Call to Ajax from users.php

```
userName: {
                    title: 'User Name',
                    list: false,
                    width: '15%',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    inputClass: 'validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20],ajax[ajaxNameCall]]'
                },
```

ValidationEngine:

```
"ajaxNameCall": {
                // remote json service location
                "url": "scripts/validationEngine/ajaxValidateFieldName.php",
                // error
                "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                "alertTextOk": "* This name is available",
                // speaks by itself
                "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
            },
```

Could I instead use the ajaxUserCallPhp function with the extraData field to pass in the userID from my form:

```
"ajaxUserCallPhp": {
                "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php",
                // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                "extraData": "name=eric",
                // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
                "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
            },
```

If so.. How do I pass the parameter? From playing about with it all I could manange was to hardcode the userID in the extraData field (which is useless). Cant figure it out =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the implementation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53023594/jQuery-Validation-Engine.rar)

Go to jQuery-Validation-Engine/demos/demoAjaxInlinePHP.html in above file extraction.

Run it on your local machine.

I have added the hidden input field which is getting passed with the ajax validation of text field.

Hope this will solve your problem :)

I have modified following files to get the things done :-

**jquery.validationEngine-en.js**

In `ajaxUserCallPhp` i have added `"extraDataDynamic": ["#xyz"],` property.

Go through the example i have attached, you will understand the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a go with it now.

Comment: Not quite. Been playing about with it an get how it works however when getting it to work with how my table is laid out is proving difficult. I am using the jtable as shown in this example: http://www.jtable.org/ with the child table. When I give it one of my field names (userID) and check firebug no parameters are passed for it? Im seriously considering just not allowing administrators to be able to edit usernames ha

Comment: ahhh hang on, think I just figured it out. Looked to see what the name of the field it was passing for the userName field and this was being passed as "Edit-userName". Changed "extraDataDynamic": ["#userID"], line in the validationEngine-en file to "extraDataDynamic": ["#Edit-UserName"], and can now see the parameter being passed. Just need to get this value to use in my select statement and should work. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

to pass extra parameters to ajax check with jquery validation engin [check this out](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/passing-extra-parameters-to-ajax-check-with-jquery-validation-engine)

Comment: hi, I found that exact same page but the link he said to follow doesnt work =(

Comment: link doesn't work because there is extra comma at the end of url
[jQuery-Validation-Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/tree/master/demos)

Comment: I have read all that and many more sites. This wasnt my first stop to just post a question and get an answer. I have been stuck on this for 2 days playing around with it and reading web posts. Its new to me and still dont understand it after reading peoples crypic posts on websites. Some places say it can be done while others say it cant then like the site you just pointed me to they have added a new line of code to the ValidationEngine file which isnt in the one I downloaded so not sure if other code is missing from javascript files that is needed and nowhere explains how to use it...

Comment: `"extraDataDynamic": ['#dynamic'],` Add this line after `"extraData": "name=eric",` and create hidden input with `name='dynamic'`.
when ajax validation call gets triggered value in the hidden field is passed with the request

Comment: in your case it is `userID`

Comment: I already have a hidden field called this: fields: {
                                            userID: {
                                                key: true,
                                                create: false,
                                                edit: false,
                                                list: false
                                            },

Comment: I added the line but when I run through it with firebug the #userID field name is passed but then the value get replaced with "". How do I get the value from this field to call it in the ajaxValidateFieldUser.php file?

Comment: You were good with jquery. Could you have a look at my latest issue an see if you have any suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542099/jtable-conditional-show-hide-edit-and-delete-buttons-based-on-owner-of-data